# Squeeze theorem with limit points

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I came across a exercise question in the continuity chapter of my textbook that I find quite strange. It goes as follows:

> Let $f,g$ and $h:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ for all $x\in D$. If $c$ is a limit point of $D$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=\lim_{x\to c} h(x)=L$, then show $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)=L$.

Is this question any different than proving the squeeze theorem of limits? I don't see how this falls into continuity at all other than the limits approaching a limit point rather than an arbitrary value in the domain. Does the fact that we're approaching a limit point change how I'm meant to approach this proof?

Comment: The *$c$ is a limit point of $D$* is present only because it is a prerequisite of the definition of limit: "Given a function $f : D \to \mathbb R$, a limit point $c$ of $D$, and $L \in \mathbb R$, we define $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=L$ to mean [blah blah blah...]".

Comment: @LeeMosher Ah I see, this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: That is the squeeze theorem, so it is just asking you to prove it rigorously (with attention to such details as $c$ needing to be a limit point of the domain). It has nothing directly to do with continuity, as it holds whether $f,g,h$ are continuous or not. However, as a basic tool of finding limits - indeed, perhaps the most powerful of limit tools, which mathematicians use all the time without even thinking about it - it is very useful in establishing continuity.